# Database designing in one to many relation

Tags: mysql, database-design

These are my tables, I've created a `tbl_relation` which have `data_id` from `tbl_data` and `tag_id` from `tbl_tags`. `data_id` can have as many `tag_ids`.

For instance in the below case:
John is associated with food, apple, orange.
Linus is associated with food, potato.

Is this the right way to do it in terms of speed and storage? as my `tbl_tags` and `tbl_data` can have at least 1 million entries and a `name` in tbl_data can be associated with at least 5 `tag_name`.

```
tbl_tags
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
| 1  | food   |
+----+--------+
| 2  | apple  |
+----+--------+
| 3  | orange |
+----+--------+
| 4  | potato |
+----+--------+
| 5  | fruit  |
+----+--------+

tbl_data
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
| 1  | John   |
+----+--------+
| 2  | Linus  |
+----+--------+
| 3  | Bill   |
+----+--------+
| 4  | Steve  |
+----+--------+
| 5  | Dennis |
+----+--------+

tbl_relation
+---------+--------+
| data_id | tag_id |
+---------+--------+
| 1       | 1      |
+---------+--------+
| 1       | 2      |
+---------+--------+
| 1       | 3      |
+---------+--------+
| 2       | 1      |
+---------+--------+
| 2       | 4      |
+---------+--------+
```

Comment: This looks a canonical way of storing your two types of data and the relationships between them.  The challenge on your part will be in creating the right indices so that joins can be done efficiently.

Comment: + Yes this is indeed the best way

Comment: A 1:many relationship is best done with an extra column in one of the tables, _not_ via an extra table.

Comment: @RickJames can you suggest something else for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Which is it?

The title says "1 to many".  In that case, `tags` should have a column saying which one person (`data_id`) is related to that tag.

Perhaps `Sam` likes `apple` and `potato` and `kiwi`?  That is, the text implies that it might be many:many.  In this case, you need a 2-column table, essentially as you describe.  Here are [*my tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) on the optimal design of such a table.  The tips address your questions of speed and space.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a many-to-many relation, as tbl_data_id can associated with multiple tbl_tags_id and vice-versa (seeing entries in tbl_relation).
If this is the case, your approach seems pretty standard as per the normal forms.

One recommedation is that create foreign key constraints on your tbl_relation table.